# listbox переместить выделение на последний элемент

Tags: c#, wpf

Необходимо сделать пролистывание ListBox в самый низ. Делаю при инициализации окна:

```
lbMsg.SelectedItem = lbMsg.Items.Count - 1;
```

Но ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
lbMsb.ScrollIntoView(lbMsg.Items[lbMsg.Items.Count - 1]);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: @Идентикон, очень рад)